# Android Realm primary key value performance

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

At my app I am using a string value with a length of 50+ characters as my "Primary Key" of each object (around 10,000 objects), is there any performance difference in fetching one or many objects where there primary value contains a string of 50+ characters vs object that contain primary key value of lets say a string with 10 characters?

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely a big difference in query writing. Because your main key is a long string and the search base in Realm based on Primary Key. You can have a better solution. Consider the following example.

I have a table called product that has the following fields.

ID  (Primary Key)   // user can't not access it. for backend Logic

product Code        // user can access it.for front logic

Product Name

And etc ...

Now I consider the main key as an ID for myself, but I only use the productCode to display to the user.
This method solves both the indexing speed problem (because the length of the main key character is shorter) and my program performance and structure are correct.